# Grep a particular length of characters

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

Let's say I have a file, foo.txt with certain contents:

```
abcds9912:        8c b2           1e12
asddb221          jj 7u 9i         e2e1
```

Now I want to `grep` only `8c, b2, jj, 7u, 9i`
i.e characters coming in pairs

So far I have tried

```
cat foo.txt | grep -Eo '[a-z0-9]{2}'
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use word boundaries, you can use:

```
\b[a-z0-9]{2}\b
```

Your command is:

```
cat foo.txt | grep -Eo '\b[a-z0-9]{2}\b'
```

Answer (score 0):

Following may also help you here.

```
awk --re-interval -v RS=" " -v FS="" '/^[[:alnum:]]{2}$/' Input_file
```

Since my `awk` version is OLD I am using `--re-interval` you could remove it in case you are using new version of `wk`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 cat foo.txt | grep -E -w -o '\w{2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use word boundary with character classes to achieve this

`$ cat foo.txt | grep -Eo '\b[[:alnum:]]{2}\b'`

or

`$ grep -Eo '\b[[:alnum:]]{2}\b' foo.txt`